# Heroku|Ruby ArgumentError: Missing required arguments:

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, amazon-web-services

I have added the aws access info in /config/initializers/carrier_wave.rb:

```
if Rails.env.production?
  CarrierWave.configure do |config|
    config.fog_credentials = {
        # Configuration for Amazon S3
        :provider              => 'AWS',
        :aws_access_key_id     => ENV['access_key'],
        :aws_secret_access_key => ENV['secret_access_key'],
    }
    config.fog_directory     =  ENV['bucket']
  end
end
```

but when i try to push to heroku, i get the following error: i am not sure what else to do, any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
JUSTINs-iMac:premidx justindoshay$ git push heroku
Fetching repository, done.
Counting objects: 23, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (11/11), done.
Writing objects: 100% (12/12), 1.09 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 12 (delta 9), reused 0 (delta 0)

-----> Removing .DS_Store files
-----> Ruby app detected
-----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
-----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.1.3
-----> Installing dependencies using 1.6.3
       Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin -j4 --deployment
       Using rake 10.3.2
       Using minitest 5.4.2
       Using thread_safe 0.3.4
       Using builder 3.2.2
       Using erubis 2.7.0
       Using mini_portile 0.6.1
       Using rack 1.6.0.beta
       Using i18n 0.7.0.beta1
       Using mime-types 2.4.3
       Using arel 6.0.0.beta2
       Using bcrypt 3.1.7
       Using sass 3.4.7
       Using json 1.8.1
       Using will_paginate 3.0.7
       Using thor 0.19.1
       Using cancan 1.6.10
       Using uber 0.0.10
       Using execjs 2.2.2
       Using formatador 0.2.5
       Using coffee-script-source 1.8.0
       Using excon 0.41.0
       Using net-ssh 2.9.1
       Using inflecto 0.0.2
       Using multi_json 1.10.1
       Using ipaddress 0.8.0
       Using gritter 1.1.0
       Using hike 1.2.3
       Using kgio 2.9.2
       Using pg 0.17.1
       Using bundler 1.6.3
       Using subexec 0.2.3
       Using rails_serve_static_assets 0.0.2
       Using tilt 1.4.1
       Using raindrops 0.13.0
       Using rails_stdout_logging 0.0.3
       Using tzinfo 1.2.2
       Using nokogiri 1.6.4
       Using rack-test 0.6.2
       Using rdoc 4.1.2
       Using mail 2.6.3
       Using bootstrap-will_paginate 0.0.10
       Using bootstrap-sass 3.2.0.0
       Using uglifier 2.5.3
       Using faker 1.4.2
       Using coffee-script 2.3.0
       Using net-scp 1.2.1
       Using fog-json 1.0.0
       Using mini_magick 3.8.0
       Using unicorn 4.8.3
       Using activesupport 4.2.0.beta4
       Using sprockets 2.12.3
       Using rails_12factor 0.0.2
       Using sdoc 0.4.0
       Using fog-core 1.24.0
       Using rails-deprecated_sanitizer 1.0.3
       Using globalid 0.3.0
       Using loofah 2.0.1
       Using jbuilder 2.2.3
       Using activemodel 4.2.0.beta4
       Using fog-brightbox 0.6.1
       Using fog-softlayer 0.3.23
       Using rails-dom-testing 1.0.4
       Using activejob 4.2.0.beta4
       Using rails-html-sanitizer 1.0.1
       Using activerecord 4.2.0.beta4
       Using carrierwave 0.10.0
       Using actionview 4.2.0.beta4
       Using fog 1.23.0
       Using friendly_id 5.0.4
       Using actionpack 4.2.0.beta4
       Using actionmailer 4.2.0.beta4
       Using sprockets-rails 3.0.0.beta1
       Using simple_form 3.0.2
       Using railties 4.2.0.beta4
       Using coffee-rails 4.0.1
       Using cells 3.11.2
       Using jquery-rails 4.0.0.beta2
       Using rails 4.2.0.beta4
       Using sass-rails 5.0.0.beta1
       Using turbolinks 2.3.0
       Your bundle is complete!
       Gems in the groups development and test were not installed.
       It was installed into ./vendor/bundle
       Bundle completed (0.79s)
       Cleaning up the bundler cache.
-----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
       Running: rake assets:precompile
       rake aborted!
       ArgumentError: Missing required arguments: aws_access_key_id, aws_secret_access_key
       /tmp/build_147081514681b2a6351adf453926ef97/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/fog-core-1.24.0/lib/fog/core/service.rb:237:in `validate_options'
       /tmp/build_147081514681b2a6351adf453926ef97/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/fog-core-1.24.0/lib/fog/core/service.rb:261:in `handle_settings'
       /tmp/build_147081514681b2a6351adf453926ef97/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/fog-core-1.24.0/lib/fog/core/service.rb:98:in `new'
       /tmp/build_147081514681b2a6351adf453926ef97/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/fog-core-1.24.0/lib/fog/storage.rb:26:in `new'
       /tmp/build_147081514681b2a6351adf453926ef97/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/carrierwave-0.10.0/lib/carrierwave/uploader/configuration.rb:83:in `eager_load_fog'
       /tmp/build_147081514681b2a6351adf453926ef97/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/carrierwave-0.10.0/lib/carrierwave/uploader/configuration.rb:96:in `fog_credentials='
       /tmp/build_147081514681b2a6351adf453926ef97/config/initializers/carrier_wave.rb:3:in `block in <top (required)>'
       /tmp/build_147081514681b2a6351adf453926ef97/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/carrierwave-0.10.0/lib/carrierwave/uploader/configuration.rb:118:in `configure'
       /tmp/build_147081514681b2a6351adf453926ef97/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/carrierwave-0.10.0/lib/carrierwave.rb:14:in `configure'
       /tmp/build_147081514681b2a6351adf453926ef97/config/initializers/carrier_wave.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
       /tmp/build_147081514681b2a6351adf453926ef97/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:246:in `load'
       /tmp/build_147081514681b2a6351adf453926ef97/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:246:in `block in load'
       /tmp/build_147081514681b2a6351adf453926ef97/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:237:in `load_dependency'
       /tmp/build_147081514681b2a6351adf453926ef97/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:246:in `load'
       /tmp/build_147081514681b2a6351adf453926ef97/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.0.beta4/lib/rails/engine.rb:648:in `block in load_config_initializer'
       /tmp/build_147081514681b2a6351adf453926ef97/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `instrument'
       /tmp/build_147081514681b2a6351adf453926ef97/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.0.beta4/lib/rails/engine.rb:647:in `load_config_initializer'
       /tmp/build_147081514681b2a6351adf453926ef97/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.0.beta4/lib/rails/engine.rb:612:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
       /tmp/build_147081514681b2a6351adf453926ef97/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.0.beta4/lib/rails/engine.rb:611:in `each'
       /tmp/build_147081514681b2a6351adf453926ef97/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.0.beta4/lib/rails/engine.rb:611:in `block in <class:Engine>'
       /tmp/build_147081514681b2a6351adf453926ef97/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.0.beta4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
       /tmp/build_147081514681b2a6351adf453926ef97/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.0.beta4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
       /tmp/build_147081514681b2a6351adf453926ef97/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.0.beta4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
       /tmp/build_147081514681b2a6351adf453926ef97/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.0.beta4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `each'
       /tmp/build_147081514681b2a6351adf453926ef97/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.0.beta4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `tsort_each_child'
       /tmp/build_147081514681b2a6351adf453926ef97/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.0.beta4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
       /tmp/build_147081514681b2a6351adf453926ef97/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.0.beta4/lib/rails/application.rb:349:in `initialize!'
       /tmp/build_147081514681b2a6351adf453926ef97/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
       /tmp/build_147081514681b2a6351adf453926ef97/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:252:in `require'
       /tmp/build_147081514681b2a6351adf453926ef97/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:252:in `block in require'
       /tmp/build_147081514681b2a6351adf453926ef97/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:237:in `load_dependency'
       /tmp/build_147081514681b2a6351adf453926ef97/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:252:in `require'
       /tmp/build_147081514681b2a6351adf453926ef97/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.0.beta4/lib/rails/application.rb:325:in `require_environment!'
       /tmp/build_147081514681b2a6351adf453926ef97/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.0.beta4/lib/rails/application.rb:438:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
       /tmp/build_147081514681b2a6351adf453926ef97/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-rails-3.0.0.beta1/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:64:in `block (2 levels) in define'
       Tasks: TOP => environment
       (See full trace by running task with --trace)
 !
 !     Precompiling assets failed.
 !

 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app

To git@heroku.com:damp-coast-2948.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:damp-coast-2948.git'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make certain that your environment variables are set

You can do this by running

heroku config

in your terminal.

This command will output your current environment variables, if you do not see  `ACCESS_KEY` or
`SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` then run the following command in terminal

```
heroku config:set ACCESS_KEY=YOUR_ACCESS_KEY_HERE
heroku config:set SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=YOUR_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY_HERE
```

Comment: I already did that, and verified on heroku that they keyds have been set. still not working.

Answer (score 0):

You must set the config vars. Go to your app on Heroku, click Settings and Reveal Config Vars.

[Heroku Docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars)

Comment: config vars were set manually but i did verify on Heroku and they are set, still no dice.

Comment: Did you use uppercase or lowercase?

Comment: uppercase or lowercase for what?

Comment: i ran: 
heroku config:set S3_ACCESS_KEY=<access key>
heroku config:set S3_SECRET_KEY=<secret key>
heroku config:set S3_BUCKET=<bucket name>

Comment: The ENV keys access_key and secret_access_key. ENV keys are typically uppercase.

Comment: the access key is all uppercase but the secret key is not because i believe it is case sensitive no?

Comment: You need to update your code and use the exact same string that appears in the Heroku config.

Comment: In your code, you have `access_key`. It needs to be `S3_ACCESS_KEY`.

Comment: changed it to reflect heroku, :S3_ACCESS_KEY AND :S3_SECRET_KEY  no luck

Comment: You don't need the colons.

Comment: when i remove the colons, i get this error:  NameError: undefined local variable or method `provider' for main:Object

Comment: in case anyone was wondering, i ran: 

rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=development

that seemed to fix it