# ArgumentError: Missing required arguments: aws_access_key_id, aws_secret_access_key When deploying to Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, amazon-s3, carrierwave, fog

Despite following this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35028081/4118694), and finding similar answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26808367/herokuruby-argumenterror-missing-required-arguments), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14098275/missing-requirement-when-using-carrierwave-and-fog-to-upload-file-to-s3), I still am getting

> ArgumentError: Missing required arguments: aws_access_key_id, aws_secret_access_key`

when I try deploying to Heroku using `Carrierwave` and `Fog` gems to upload images to Amazon S3.

/config/initializers/carrierwave.rb:

```
if Rails.env.production?
  CarrierWave.configure do |config|
    config.fog_credentials = {

      :provider              => 'AWS',
      :aws_access_key_id     => ENV['S3_ACCESS_KEY'],
      :aws_secret_access_key => ENV['S3_SECRET_KEY'],
      :region                => ENV['S3_REGION']
    }
    config.fog_directory     =  ENV['S3_BUCKET']
  end
end
```

And I set the Heroku config like this:

```
S3_ACCESS_KEY: ABCDEFGHIJKPMNOPQRS
S3_BUCKET:     mybucket12345
S3_REGION:     us-west-2
S3_SECRET_KEY: 1234567890ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWZYZ1234
```

Logs:

```
Running: rake assets:precompile
remote:        rake aborted!
remote:        ArgumentError: Missing required arguments: aws_access_key_id, aws_secret_access_key
remote:        /tmp/build_d869b0ccafedcf0c55d666f657f499ac/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/fog-core-1.43.0/lib/fog/core/service.rb:244:in `validate_options'
remote:        /tmp/build_d869b0ccafedcf0c55d666f657f499ac/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/fog-core-1.43.0/lib/fog/core/service.rb:268:in `handle_settings'
remote:        /tmp/build_d869b0ccafedcf0c55d666f657f499ac/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/fog-core-1.43.0/lib/fog/core/service.rb:98:in `new'
remote:        /tmp/build_d869b0ccafedcf0c55d666f657f499ac/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/fog-core-1.43.0/lib/fog/core/services_mixin.rb:16:in `new'
remote:        /tmp/build_d869b0ccafedcf0c55d666f657f499ac/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/fog-core-1.43.0/lib/fog/storage.rb:27:in `new'
remote:        /tmp/build_d869b0ccafedcf0c55d666f657f499ac/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/carrierwave-0.11.2/lib/carrierwave/uploader/configuration.rb:83:in `eager_load_fog'
remote:        /tmp/build_d869b0ccafedcf0c55d666f657f499ac/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/carrierwave-0.11.2/lib/carrierwave/uploader/configuration.rb:96:in `fog_credentials='
remote:        /tmp/build_d869b0ccafedcf0c55d666f657f499ac/config/initializers/carrierwave.rb:2:in `block in <top (required)>'
remote:        /tmp/build_d869b0ccafedcf0c55d666f657f499ac/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/carrierwave-0.11.2/lib/carrierwave/uploader/configuration.rb:118:in `configure'
remote:        /tmp/build_d869b0ccafedcf0c55d666f657f499ac/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/carrierwave-0.11.2/lib/carrierwave.rb:14:in `configure'
remote:        /tmp/build_d869b0ccafedcf0c55d666f657f499ac/config/initializers/carrierwave.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
remote:        /tmp/build_d869b0ccafedcf0c55d666f657f499ac/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `load'
remote:        /tmp/build_d869b0ccafedcf0c55d666f657f499ac/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `block in load'
remote:        /tmp/build_d869b0ccafedcf0c55d666f657f499ac/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in `load_dependency'
remote:        /tmp/build_d869b0ccafedcf0c55d666f657f499ac/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `load'
remote:        /tmp/build_d869b0ccafedcf0c55d666f657f499ac/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:648:in `block in load_config_initializer'
remote:        /tmp/build_d869b0ccafedcf0c55d666f657f499ac/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `instrument'
remote:        /tmp/build_d869b0ccafedcf0c55d666f657f499ac/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:647:in `load_config_initializer'
remote:        /tmp/build_d869b0ccafedcf0c55d666f657f499ac/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:612:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
remote:        /tmp/build_d869b0ccafedcf0c55d666f657f499ac/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:611:in `each'
remote:        /tmp/build_d869b0ccafedcf0c55d666f657f499ac/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:611:in `block in <class:Engine>'
remote:        /tmp/build_d869b0ccafedcf0c55d666f657f499ac/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
remote:        /tmp/build_d869b0ccafedcf0c55d666f657f499ac/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
remote:        /tmp/build_d869b0ccafedcf0c55d666f657f499ac/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
remote:        /tmp/build_d869b0ccafedcf0c55d666f657f499ac/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `each'
remote:        /tmp/build_d869b0ccafedcf0c55d666f657f499ac/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `tsort_each_child'
remote:        /tmp/build_d869b0ccafedcf0c55d666f657f499ac/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
remote:        /tmp/build_d869b0ccafedcf0c55d666f657f499ac/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in `initialize!'
remote:        /tmp/build_d869b0ccafedcf0c55d666f657f499ac/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
remote:        /tmp/build_d869b0ccafedcf0c55d666f657f499ac/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
remote:        /tmp/build_d869b0ccafedcf0c55d666f657f499ac/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `block in require'
remote:        /tmp/build_d869b0ccafedcf0c55d666f657f499ac/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in `load_dependency'
remote:        /tmp/build_d869b0ccafedcf0c55d666f657f499ac/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
remote:        /tmp/build_d869b0ccafedcf0c55d666f657f499ac/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/application.rb:328:in `require_environment!'
remote:        /tmp/build_d869b0ccafedcf0c55d666f657f499ac/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/application.rb:448:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
remote:        /tmp/build_d869b0ccafedcf0c55d666f657f499ac/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-rails-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:62:in `block (2 levels) in define'
remote:        /tmp/build_d869b0ccafedcf0c55d666f657f499ac/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.3.0/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
remote:        Tasks: TOP => environment
remote:        (See full trace by running task with --trace)
remote:  !
remote:  !     Precompiling assets failed.
remote:  !
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
```

Comment: Could you share the output you see in the logs when trying to deploy?

Comment: @geemus added the log.

Comment: Sorry it has been frustrating, I've seen this before and it's usually something that is simple (which unfortunately tends to make it easy to overlook).

I noticed your code wraps the config setting with `Rails.env.production?`, is it possible that this returns false in the Heroku context? If so, the configuration would never be set, which would cause this error.

Otherwise, I'm not sure. When I've seen this before it has often been a typo on one of the keys (or similar), but that doesn't appear to be the case here.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

1. Add to your gemfile: `gem "figaro"`
2. `figaro heroku:set -e production`
3. `rake figaro:heroku`
4. Push again to heroku